# Redhat openshift - rails mysql response takes more than 20sec

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, redhat, openshift

I have rails (v3.0.9) with mysql running on Redhat open shift.

I have seen that it takes around **35-40 sec** to get JSON response made up of all records from a single table. There are around 10000 records in this single table.

Is there any way to make it faster? i.e To get the response atleast within 10sec.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd look to paginate the results. With you requesting a JSON response, I assume you are using AJAX to load these results?

Though I haven't used it before, I believe you can 'stream' records for large tables using the mysql2 gem. https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#streaming. Before that, however, I'd paginate. No need to load 10k records onto a page in one go.

Also, cache the results and invalidate the cache when important data changes.